# Replace potentiometer for Kemo M012 Power Control

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, potentiometer

The potentiometer of my ([Kemo M012 Power Control](https://www.kemo-electronic.de/en/Light-Sound/Effects/Modules/M012-Power-Control-110-240-V-AC-1200-VA.php)) is mechanically broken and I would like to replace it.

However, I am unsure whether the replacement needs to meet any specific characteristics or if any off-the-shelf potentiometer (with the same maximum resistance) should suffice.

Is there actually any load going through the potentiometer ?

Comment: Potentiometers are usually linear or logarithmic, you would need to know which one you are replacing as well. If it is a rheostat (another name for potentiometer, usually used more often in power applications), there could be quite a bit of load going through it, so it would be best to replace it with one that can handle the same power dissipation.

Comment: @jfrohnhofen "pot" is the usual vernacular shortening of potentiometer, at least in English-speaking regions.

Comment: @Hearth - Indeed, but FYI in German at least, it's *poti*. See [here](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/german-to-english/tech-engineering/279022-poti.html) for confirmation. I've changed the text in the question to the full word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that in that black box is a phase controlled triac, and that the potentiometer needs to withstand full 240VAC and provide safety isolation, so don't use a cheap potentiometer with metal shaft and body.